# "Reseller" or "re-seller"?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

Which spelling is correct — *reseller* or *re-seller*?

I was writing a question on another Stack Exchange site, and I wrote *reseller*, but the editor underlined that as an incorrect spelling. Microsoft Word accepts it however, but Microsoft Encarta Dictionary has no entry for *reseller*, *resell*, or *reselling*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it "re-offend" or "reoffend"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195711/is-it-re-offend-or-reoffend)

Answer (score 3):

The OED has citations for unhyphenated ‘resellers’ from 1891, 1979 and 2007.

Answer (score 2):

**Reseller** is perfectly fine (at least in American English). Here's [an example](http://www.apple.com/buy/) on the Apple website, which allows you to search for 'licensed resellers' (right side of page).